# Convert between python array and .NET Array

Tags: .net, python, arrays, ironpython, marshalling

I have a python method that returns a Python byte array.array('c').

Now, I want to copy this array using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy. This method however expects a .NET array.

```
import array
from System.Runtime.InteropServices import Marshal

bytes = array.array('c')
bytes.append('a')
bytes.append('b')
bytes.append('c')
Marshal.Copy(bytes, dest, 0, 3)
```

Is there a way to make this work without copying the data? If not, how do I convert the data in the Python array to the .NET array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert a python array to a .NET Array:

```
import array
from System import Array, Char

x = array.array('c', 'abc')

y = Array[Char](x)
```

Here is some information on creating typed Arrays in IronPython:
http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Typed_Arrays_in_IronPython

Comment: Thanks for responding. I already got a resolution to my marshaling issue on the IronPython newgroup (http://groups.google.com/group/ironpy/t/91a344a5ddb7df39)